# matplotlib: what does the parameter `which` do in tick_params

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
.
.
.
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=16)
```

I checked the parameter "which" in [matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params](http://nullege.com/codes/search/matplotlib.pyplot.tick_params?fulldoc=1). It is said that Default is 'major'; apply arguments to *which* ticks.

So I tried to change which='major' to 'minor'. It seems only the label size changes smaller. But shouldn't the label size being controlled by the parameter 'labelsize'?

I also tried to change `labelsize=16` to `labelsize=106` while keeping `which='minor'`. It turns out nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `which` indeed selects to which of `"minor"`, `"major"`, or `"both"` of them the rest of the arguments apply.

Since by default, there are no minor ticklabels in a matplotlib plot, even though you change their size with

```
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=16)
```

you don't see any change. But note that *if* you had minor ticklabels in your plot, their size *would* change.

In below example, we turn the minor ticks on by using a locator and we turn the minor ticklabels on by using a formatter. Then `ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=8)` gives the minor ticklabels a fontsize of 8.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, ScalarFormatter

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,10,20,30], [0,2,1,2])

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(ScalarFormatter())

ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=16, pad=12)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=8)

plt.show()
```